# Why Triceratops' frill reabsorbed the triangular epiossifications on the edge of the frill?

Tags: development, palaeontology, dinosaurs

Why *Triceratops*' frill reabsorbed the triangular epiossifications on the edge of the frill?

Juvenile and even sub-adult *Triceratops* had triangular prongs on the edge of the frill, called "epocciptials" or "epiossification". However, in very mature specimen the frill lacks those triangular prongs and transitional specimens show how the epiossification fuse with the frill to form a wave-like edge and later even a smooth edge.

A scientific description of this ontogeny can be found here:

> Horner, John R; Goodwin (2006). ["Major cranial changes during Triceratops ontogeny"](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspb.2006.3643). Proceedings of the Royal Society B (273): 2757–2761. doi:10.1098/rspb.2006.3643.

Short summary by Horner: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2_Fcp6W7U4

The question is: why? What benefit did this modification (the smoothening of the frill's edge) give to *Triceratops*?

---

### General Images

[image: Triceratops]

**Figure 1.1:** this *Triceratops* exhibits prominent triangular epiossifications. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Triceratops_skull_frills.jpg

[image: Triceratops MOR]

**Figure 1.2:** growth serie of *Triceratops*.
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Triceratops_ontogeny.jpg

[image: Triceratops AMNH]

**Figure 1.3:** a skeleton of adult *Triceratops* in New York's AMNH. The frill shows a smooth edge.
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Triceratops_AMNH_01.jpg

---

### *Triceratops horridus*

[image]

**Figure 2.1:** Triceratops horridus Marsh, 1889, shows scalloped edge https://www.si.edu/object/triceratops-horridus-marsh-1889%3Anmnhpaleobiology_3383580

**Figure 2.2:** https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Triceratops_horridus_skull_in_the_Gallery_of_Paleontology_-_Paris.jpg
Shows transition from scalloped to wavy edge.

[image]

**Figure 2.3:** Triceratops horridus showing wavy-to-smooth edge.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Triceratops_Hendrickx2.jpg

[image: Triceratops AMNH]

**Figure 2.4:** a skeleton of adult *Triceratops* in New York's AMNH. The frill shows a smooth edge.
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Triceratops_AMNH_01.jpg

---

*Triceratops prorsus*

Comment: Got a couple of different species there. Bottom photo is *Triceratops horridus*; top two photos are *T. prorsus* I think, though could be other ceratopsids. Fusion of bones is common with age - our skulls do it.

Answer (score 0):

As Bob out the bottom image is a different species. So the comparison is faulty.

as for why bones fuse with age, that is very normal, it happens to bone in thousands of species our own included. The parts are separated by growth surfaces, when growth slows down aka adulthood, those surfaces fuse for strength. This is so predictable in humans the fusion of different bones can be used to age a skeleton. We see this in dinosaurs too but without living one to correlate fusion times with it can't be used to age specimens well.

As for why the angle of the epocciptials change , that's easy, the number of epocciptials do not change so as the frill gets larger the epocciptials need to get wider. They can either grow in all dimensions or just get wider making the angle shallower. Whatever function the epocciptials have must not be impacted by getting shallower so that's what they do saving bone and horn. considering how much mass they would add if they grew in all dimensions its not even that surprising.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0305440388900829

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6427487/

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3864909/

Comment: That bones fuse with age, I know. The question is why the triangular epiossifications reabsorbed and disappear and not merely fuse but retain their shape. The scalloped frill of a Triceratops has a defensive advantage and probably also a display value from the prominent epiossifications in other ceratopsids).

Comment: They don't, you are looking at two different species. if you count the number of epocciptials they stay the same in the same species throughout its life. in Horridus the epocciptials are tiny, so they are just really hard to see in the adults as their width is drastically greater than their length.

Comment: I added Figs 2.1-2.4 consisting only of *Triceratops horridus* (however, I could not determine from the images what was the age of the animal it came from).

Comment: @Triceratops from my skimming of the literature it seems you are not alone here - the problem is that formerly there were a bunch of species, all classified on the frill edges. However, with the recent clumping, there is now diversity in the frill edges within each species - so some have it and some don't within the same species, this means that it likely isn't age dependent, so your premise fails to some extent there.

Comment: @bob1 if there is a variation within a species it is likely sexual dimorphism. but if you look at the series in fig 2 the epocciptials do not disappear. the only figuire without epocciptials is 2.4 which could be not collected, a diffrent species, or even destroyed it is a very old specimen. If you think they disappear you will need to demonstrate that.

Comment: @John I'm no expert on dinosaur systematics at all, so I don't know that they disappear or not, just that there is some diversity in size/shape across a species. Sexual dimorphism is definitely a possibility, that hadn't occurred to me.